# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors with zeroes on the diagonal and ones everywhere else.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I have been working on this problem for a couple hours and am completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $A$ be the $n \times n$ matrix which has zeros on the main diagonal and ones everywhere else. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: what have you done? what does $A-\lambda I$ look like?

Comment: I have found out that λ1 = n-1 and λ2 through λn = -1, but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: *Hint* $A+I$ is a matrix with rank $1$. This means the eigenspace of $-1$ has dimension $n-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $\lambda=-1$, then 
$$
A-\lambda I
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \dotsc & 1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & \dotsc & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But $A-\lambda I$ has rank $1$, so $\lambda_1=-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with geometric multiplicity $n-1$. The eigenspace $E_{\lambda_1}$ is the nullspace of this matrix. Can you find it? Hint: it has dimension $n-1$.

Now, note that $\operatorname{trace}A=0$ so $\lambda_2=n-1$ is the other eigenvalue of $A$. The eigenspace $E_{\lambda_2}$ is the nullspace of $A-\lambda_2 I$. Can you find it too?

Comment: "${\rm rank}(A)=0$" should be ${\rm trace}(A)=0$, yes?  Only a zero matrix has rank $0$.

Comment: whoops trace yes

Comment: Your $\lambda_2$ is clearly wrong unless $n=2$.

Comment: Ok I think all the typos have been corrected, correct?